# Is there a clean way to convert a CNPostalAddress to a CNMutablePostalAddress?

Tags: swift, ios-contacts, cnpostaladdress

I want to modify the values of a `CNPostalAddress`, which I obtained from the `postalAddress` property of a `CLPlacemark`.

Since `CNPostalAddress` has immutable properties, I want to convert it to a `CNMutablePostalAddress`. However, there doesn't seem to be a clean way to do that. My current method is this:

```
extension CNPostalAddress {
    var mutableAddress: CNMutablePostalAddress {
        let address = CNMutablePostalAddress()

        address.city = city
        address.country = country
        address.postalCode = postalCode
        address.state = state
        address.street = street

        [...]

        return address
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this conversion?

Comment: I don't think so. CNMutablePostalAddress has no initializers and you can't cast from CNPostalAddress to CNMutablePostalAddress

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, that's what I found as well. Seems strange, since `NSMutableAttributedString`, another non-Swifty class actually has an initializer with an `NSMutableString` parameter.

Comment: +1, not sure why this was down voted. I do a lot with CNContact, didn't know the CNPostalAddress is used elsewhere, so this was good-for-me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CNPostalAddress` is a class that extends `NSObject`. This means you have access to `mutableCopy`.

```
let contact = ... // some CNPostalAddress instance obtained elsewhere
let newContact = contact.mutableCopy() as! CNMutablePostalAddress
newContact.city = "Here"
```

No need to copy individual properties.

Or as an update to your extension:

```
extension CNPostalAddress {
    var mutableAddress: CNMutablePostalAddress {
        return mutableCopy() as! CNMutablePostalAddress
    }
}

let contact = ... // some CNPostalAddress instance obtained elsewhere
let newContact = contact.mutableAddress
newContact.city = "Here"
```